# How to set binary file download in ErrorDocument or DirectryIndex on Apache webserver

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, malware

Just a theoretical security question that come to my mind.

Is it possible to set Apache web-hosting via httaccess to present you with binary file instead of document when you access a directory index or an error document?

It tried something like this, but it did not work. I am sure that it is possible since some malware I came across use this technique to spread. Anyone has an idea how is it done?

```
<Directory /aaa>
    DirectoryIndex binaryPayload.exe
</Directory>

ErrorDocument 404 binaryPayload.exe
```

This is an obvious security risk. How would you recommend to set your Apache with multiple virtual hosting to resist this kind of thread?

Comment: apache will serve up anything you tell it to. but merely pointing a person's browser at a .exe file is not generally going to magically make their pc execute that file. not without some major internal security problems and/or social engineering. At most they'd just get prompted to download the file.

Comment: Sure, but there is a great risk they execute it once the download is complete. Especially when it has some popular name - some game, crack or even porn.